# Installing PCI-E Graphics Card: Power Supply?

Tags: installation, graphics-card, power-supply

I am installing a new graphics card in my computer (HD Radeon 6950: Power Color Series) and on the top right end of the card there are two different sets of pins for a power cords to go into. The first one is 8 pins and the other is 6.

My old one only had two 6 pin power ports (or whatever you call them?). I have two "power cords", one is a 6 pin which has another 2 pins (total of 2x4: 8) branching off from the main one and then another six pin cord. How do I know if I should do 8:6 or 6:6? Or is it just implied that you always fill all power pin slots? I just want to make sure I am doing it right because I don't want to ruin anything! Hope this wasn't too confusing, I tried to be descriptive as possible. Thanks!

Comment: Here is a link for a picture of the card: http://www.legitreviews.com/article/1488/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [page](http://www.legitreviews.com/article/1488/3/) you've linked to:

> The AMD Radeon HD 6970 uses both an 8-pin and a 6-pin PCIe power connector located at the end of the video card on the top corner.  AMD didn't tell us what the power supply requirements are, so we pinged XFX and they were happy to let us know. AMD recommends a 550 Watt or greater power supply with one 75W 6-pin PCIe connector and one 150W 8-pin PCIe connector on the Radeon HD 6970.  The AMD Radeon HD 6950 requires a 500W or greater power supply with two 75W 6-pin PCIe connectors.

You need to plug power into **both** sockets.

Comment: haha! Yes, thank you, I had just found that! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer, but if someone could **affirm my conclusion** that would be great. I found this on a website:

"The AMD Radeon HD 6970 uses both an 8-pin and a 6-pin PCIe power connector located at the end of the video card on the top corner.  AMD didn't tell us what the power supply requirements are, so we pinged XFX and they were happy to let us know. AMD recommends a 550 Watt or greater power supply with one 75W 6-pin PCIe connector and one 150W 8-pin PCIe connector on the Radeon HD 6970.  **The AMD Radeon HD 6950 requires a 500W or greater power supply with two 75W 6-pin PCIe connectors.**"

Checking my power supply [model](http://www.cyberpowerpc.com/spec/getspec.aspx?n=POWERSUPPLY&v=800%20Watts%20-%20XtremeGear%20Gaming%20Power%20Supply%20-%20Quad%20SLI%20Ready) I have an **800W**, **which would suggest I use two 6-pin connectors?** Thanks.